# Understanding PSR-4

Tags: composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I have file structure like:

```
├─ vendor/
└─ src/
   ├─ Acme/
   │  ├─ Foul/
   │  │   └─ Nest.php
   │  └─ Universal.php
   └─ Foo.php
```

I am trying to use PSR-4 auto loading using Composer. This code:

```
$obj = new Acme\Universal();
```

Gives me an error: `Fatal error: Class 'Acme\Universal' not found in ...`

If I use this snippet in `composer.json`:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
}
```

But if I use

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Acme\\": ["src/", "src/Acme/"]}
}
```

everything works fine. I can even access

```
$otherObj = new Acme\Foul\Nest();
```

Please note that I have run `composer install` every time I changed the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

PSR-4 does not include the prefix in the path to search for, PSR-0 does.

So `Acme\Universal` with `"Acme\\": "src/"` will be searched in `src/Universal.php` with PSR-4 and in `src/Acme/Universal.php` with PSR-0.

In this case, you should move the contents of the `src/Acme/` directory to `src/`. The PSR-4 was created exactly to remove these directories with only one subdirectory and no other files.